# Using Dynamic values in the Reply To field in Sprout Forms Notifications

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I'm looking to have a Dynamic 'Reply To' for a notification when an entry is saved from a form submissions.

I'm using the below which is what the field is named in my form, but it seems it's not allowed?

```
{email}
```

[image]

Comment: Using sprout forms 3.0.0-beta.44 I get the same validation error.. ( I have a email field with handle email in the form...) [![screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xT1N.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xT1N.png)

Comment: @Pieter-JanDeBruyne This is resolved in the latest release (v3.0.0-beta.50)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into the same issue, asked the support team, and they confirmed it's a bug.

Workaround is to comment out this line:
https://github.com/barrelstrength/craft-sprout-base/blob/v2/src/app/email/elements/NotificationEmail.php#L481

Tried it and it works fine.

They said it would be fixed in an upcoming release.

Comment: This has been fixed in Sprout Forms v3.0.0-beta.21.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic values work in Sprout Forms as of Sprout Forms v3.0.0-beta.21.

You can target any value that is being submitted by your form using the shorthand syntax from your example `{email}` or object syntax `{{ object.email }}`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in 3.0.0-beta.44, but the linked workaround is no longer accurate.

Comment: @sarah3585 we were able to recreate this issue and we'll update this post once a fix is in place